# c++ heterogeneous container, get entry as type

Tags: c++, templates, containers, heterogeneous-array

I have the following simple implementation of a Heterogeneous container:

```
struct Container {
    struct HolderBase {
    };

    template<typename S>
    struct Holder : HolderBase {
        Holder(S* s) : s_(s) {}
        S* s_;
    };

    template<typename S>
    void push_back(S* s) {
        h_.push_back(new Holder<S>(s));
    }

    vector<HolderBase*> h_;

    template<typename B>
    B* get(int i) {
        //magic here
    }
};
```

Here's how to use it:

```
struct ElementBase {};
struct Element : ElementBase {};

int main()
{
    Container container;
    container.push_back(new Element);
    ElementBase* elementBase = container.get<ElementBase>(0);
}
```

I can add entries of any type to it. But I can't figure out how to implement a function to retrieve elements, as some type, which may be the same as the entry or a base class to it.

What I need seems to be both virtual and template at the same time, which is not possible.

Comment: Why "reinvent the wheel" when you can just use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) (or [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/any.html))? Or perhaps do a redesign so you don't need to use heterogeneous containers or type-erasure?

Comment: `any` can not do that. An `any_cast` can only cast to the actual type. Not to a base type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to have *exactly* what you want without much pain and inconvenience (for example, registering all classes you want to work with in some kind of central repository).

Here's one way to do *almost* what you want that can perhaps be useful.

```
class HolderBase
{
  public:
    virtual ~HolderBase() = default;    
    template <class X> X* get() { return dynamic_cast<X*>(this); }
};

template <class T>
class Holder : public HolderBase, public T
{
  public:
    using T::T;
};
```

Your container is then just a `vector<unique_ptr<HolderBase>>` or whatever bunch-of-pointers you fancy.

Test drive:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default;
    A(int a) : a(a) {};
    int a;
};

struct B : A {
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), b(b) {};
    int b;
};

struct C : A {
    C(int a, int c) : A(a), c(c) {};
    int c;
};


int main () {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<HolderBase>> v;
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Holder<B>>(7,40));
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Holder<C>>(0,42));

    A* a = v[0]->template get<A>();
    B* b = v[0]->template get<B>();
    C* c = v[0]->template get<C>();

    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << "\n";

    a = v[1]->template get<A>();
    b = v[1]->template get<B>();
    c = v[1]->template get<C>();

    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The main problem with this solution is that the elements can't be constructed, and THEN put into the container. I rewrote the rest of my problem to handle this, and it now work perfectly. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

> how to implement a function to retrieve elements, as some type, which may be the same as the entry or a base class to it.

To get the same entry, the simplest way preserving your current design is to use RTTI.

firstly, make the type-erasing base polymorphic:

```
struct HolderBase { virtual ~HolderBase() = default; };
```

then, you can just dynamic_cast:

```
template<typename B>
B* get(int i) {
    if( auto holder = dynamic_cast<Holder<B>*>(h_[i]) )
    {
       return holder->s_;
    }
    else
       return nullptr;
}
```

this will return `nullptr` whenever the dynamic type of the object pointed to by `h_[i]` is the wrong type. You may also throw or provide a throwing `get<B&>` overload as well.

Note that in C++17, we already have std::any (originated from boost.any) basically doing the same, but with a standard interface (to become idiomatic soon) and all details already worked out; so, it's strongly advisable to use it instead of rolling out your own.

---

The problem of getting an entry as a base is harder though; the simplest solution is to pass the allowed target types to pushback, something like:

```
template<typename... T,typename S>
void push_back_as(S* s) {
   static_assert( ( std::is_base_of_v<T,S> && ...) );

   h_.push_back(new Holder<S,T...>(s)); // where Holder<S,T0,...> inherits from properly defined Holder<S>,Holder<T0>,...
}
```

or use some other non-intrusive means for registering the target types (eg. a trait class).

otherwise, I don't think this is *generally* possible as of now (it will be when we'll have compile-time reflection).

Comment: this only works if you insert the element with the same type as you retrieve it with. your dynamic_cast will return nullptr, because Holder<B> is not a base class of Holder<S>.

Comment: @Xplatformer, ah I missed the "or a base class to it." part ... editing ...

Comment: @XPlatformer, do you want get<T> to accept a *specific* set of bases or *any* base of T ?

Comment: any base of T, please.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes you might want to define `template<class Base, class Derived> bool is_base_of(Derived const&) { return std::is_base_of_v<Base, Derived>; }`. [test cases on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/916a76574733bddf).

Comment: @YSC, why would that help ? if I got OP requirements correctly, get cannot know Derived ( and pushback cannot know Base ) ...